# Router/gateway that keeps a rolling history of websites visited?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, history, gateway

I am looking for a wireless (A)DSL modem router/gateway that keeps a history of websites visited through the router? If it could store a few weeks of history at a time, that would be great.

There's a screenshot in this answer that does exactly that. But I don't know what make or model it is: https://superuser.com/a/47733.

If there are a few different makes of router that have this functionality, it'd be great to have a list of them too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Most routers have the ability to turn on logs. Its just a matter of enabling the logs. As for how long they keep the logs before being rotated, that may be different depending on the model. 
You can also look into getting a router on the DD-WRT supported devices list and use that to run logs.

http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Supported_Devices

It doesnt explicitly state that it will log the sites visited but DD-WRT should do that without a problem.

http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Logging_with_DD-WRT

Answer (score 0):

Anything running DD-WRT would do that (Not Purchasable)

D-Links do this very well by default

Not sure about netgear

Lynksys/cisco normally have to be flashed (DD-WRT) to add this functionality.

Be one in this screenshot looks like a D-Link

Also: Did you try to message JT using the email provided in his autobiography about the screenshot?

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at D-Link. DD-WRT looks interesting, but I'd prefer to not modify the firmware on the router. Hoping for a router that has the functionality already built-in :)

Comment: Then D-Link would be your best bet. I'm glad I could help. Please, if you find my answer satisfying after your experimentation, feel free to give it a vote up!